# Add var +1 to Label on button press (kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Source func - add_click

add +1 to self.click to Label (self.RightBar) by press button

I write a function for the game (clicker), the essence of which is that by pressing the button in the label a counter was added.

```
    def add_click(self, instance):

        self.click += 1

    def build(self):

        self.click = "0"

        Body = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical",
                                            size_hint = [1,.8],
                                            spacing = 0.7)

        Land = BoxLayout()

        LeftBar = Image(source = "/storage/emulated/0/kivy/image/84.jpg", size_hint = [None, None], size = [1080, 610])

        self.RightBar = Label(text = "MONEY:" + "\n" + "\nUNITS:" + "\n" + "\nDAY:" + "\n" + "\nCLICKS:" + "  " + self.click,
                                        size_hint = [.3,1],
                                        valign = "top",
                                        halign = "left",
                                        text_size = [750,900])

        Land.add_widget(LeftBar);
        Land.add_widget(self.RightBar);

        Body.add_widget(Land);

        NavBar = BoxLayout(size_hint = [1, .55],
                                                spacing = 0.8)

        Body.add_widget(NavBar);

        Body.add_widget(Button(text = "*click*",
                                        font_size = 20,                                                                 background_normal = "",
                                        background_color = [.11,.11,.10,.4],
                                        size_hint = [1,1.7],
                                        on_press = self.add_click));

        return Body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

## Step 1

From string:

```
self.click = "0"
```

To numeric:

```
self.click = 0
```

## Step 2

From:

```
self.RightBar = ... + self.click, ...
```

To:

```
self.RightBar = ... + str(self.click), ...
```

## Snippets

```
def build(self):
    self.click = 0
    ...
    self.RightBar = Label(text = "MONEY:" + "\n" + "\nUNITS:" + "\n" + "\nDAY:" + "\n" + "\nCLICKS:" + "  " + str(self.click)
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Perhaps like yours too it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by rewriting the function like that:

```
def add_click(self, instance):
    self.click = int(self.click)
    self.click += 1
    self.click = str(self.click)
    self.RightBar.text = str("MONEY:"+"\n"+"\nUNITS:"+"\n"+"\nDAY:"+"\n"+"\nCLICKS:"+" "+self.click)
```